# Prefetch Image Dimensions and set height of CardView Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, picasso

Currently I am using Picasso to load image stored on Firebase. The problem is that when I am fetching the image, initially CardView has very small size and then when image is fetched it goes to bigger size as shown below.

[image]

Is there any way to prefetch image dimensions and hence cardview does not change size before and after loading.

Comment: You should set a default image while downloading image

Answer (score -1):

You can use a placeholder image by using the ***.placeholder(R.drawable.image_name)***

***in XML***

```
......
......
......
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/partner_post_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />
......
......
......
```

Like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(imageURL)
.error(android.R.drawable.error_image)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default)
.fit()
.centerCrop()
.into(postImage);
```

Comment: check my answer @nd1010

Comment: but i am faster then you :D

Comment: ohhhhhh thats fine :D